# Azure load balancer A record

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I need an advice re Azure load balancer. 
**First of all current status**

- We have a virtual machine with IIS7 which runs 10 different websites. We use godaddy for domain management. Each of urls are pointed to the virtual machine IP address via A record.

**Future plans**

We want to make our websites more robust by adding one more virtual machine which will be a backup if something goes wrong with the main machine. Literally we are planing to keep second machine shut down and run it only if the main machine goes off (for any reason).

I'm thinking to achieve this via Azure load balancer. I founded a few tutorials which explain creating load balancer but haven't managed to find any info how to point existing url to load balancer.

Or to re phrase my question which IP address will the load balancer have? The main virtual machine or?

Thanks

Comment: A Load Balancer typically has its own IP Address.  So your URL's would point to the IP Address of the Load Balancer, and the Load Balancer would distribute the Traffic based on the pool of Virtual Machines under it and the rules you create on the Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your Virtual Machine you will see there's a cloud service associated with it. The cloud service is the one renponsible to provide public ip addresses, hostname, auto scale, load-balance to endpoints and a series of other functionalities to one VM or a set of VMs.

What enables or disables the load balance of your cloud service is something called load-balanced set for endpoints. You can have a single endpoint for a VM or a load-balanced set to distribute a specific type of traffic between multiple virtual machines or services. Check the guide below to find out how to setup:

[Configure a load-balanced set](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-load-balance/)

Basically what you want is to create a new VM and add it to the same cloud service as the one you have running today. Don't use quick create, use custom create otherwise you will not have the option to select the cloud service. The second step will be creating a load-balance set for all the endpoints you need both vms to answer. For example, creating a load-balanced set for port 80 would make the incoming requests to be balanced (round-robin) between your 2 vms.

The VIP of all the VMs in the same cloud service will be the same. You won't have to change anything on your public DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Updating link to Azure load balancer documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/